# HTML rowspan not working with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a table with javascript, some of the rows I want to have `rowspan`, but Its not working. For example if a row has a rowspan of 4 then It only shows a maximum of 2 rowspans in Mozzila Firefox. But it Google Chrome It doesnt work at all.

```
    if (currentLectures.length === 1) { //If there is only one element in the array.
          start = currentLectures[0].start;
          end = currentLectures[0].end;
          alert(end);

          rowspan = end - start;   //Rowspan if the lecture times are more than one hour.
          column = document.createElement("td"); //Creating a <td> element.
          column.setAttribute("class", "lectures");
          column.setAttribute("rowspan", rowspan);

          lecture = document.createTextNode(currentLectures[0].name);

          column.appendChild(lecture);
          tableRow.appendChild(column); //Adding the <td> element to the current row.

    }
```

This is the html output I get:

```
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="lectures"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    12:00
                </th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I am not sure why the rowspan is not working here. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that the inside of that `if` statement is actually executing?

Comment: @ JLRishe Yes, I can see the table

Answer (score 0):

```
var column = document.createElement("td"); //Creating a <td> element.
column.innerHTML = '3';
column.rowSpan = 2
document.getElementById("tr_demo").appendChild(column);
```

try it?

http://jsfiddle.net/exrw1o2p/